# How can I use the famo.us CDN links in a meteor application?

Tags: meteor, famo.us

With the release of famo.us, it has all the libraries as CDN hosted libs.  How can I use these from within a meteor app?

I get a lot of problems with the "define" in the famo.us code...

What I've done is create a new meteor app, and then from the famo.us boilerplate, I've taken the html and put it into a client folder so it looks like

```
<head>  
  <title>famo.us App</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

        <!-- shims for backwards compatibility -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.famo.us/lib/functionPrototypeBind.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.famo.us/lib/classList.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.famo.us/lib/requestAnimationFrame.js"></script>

        <!-- module loader -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.famo.us/lib/require.js"></script>

        <!-- famous -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.2/famous.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.2/famous.min.js"></script>

        <!-- app code -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require.config({'localhost:3000': 'public/'});
            require(['main']);
        </script>

</head>

<body>  
</body>
```

Then I've taken the main.js in the src folder of the boiler plate and put it into the client/compatibility folder of meteor.  But it doesn't really work.  Comes back with

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

from main.js

and main.js looks like

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    // import dependencies
    var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
    var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
    var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
    var ImageSurface = require('famous/surfaces/ImageSurface');

    // create the main context
    var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

    // your app here
    var logo = new ImageSurface({
        size: [200, 200],
        content: 'http://code.famo.us/assets/famous_logo.svg',
        classes: ['double-sided']
    });

    var initialTime = Date.now();
    var centerSpinModifier = new Modifier({
        origin: [0.5, 0.5],
        transform : function(){
            return Transform.rotateY(.002 * (Date.now() - initialTime));
        }
    });

    mainContext.add(centerSpinModifier).add(logo);
});
```

from looking at the source, it looks like its because meteor has compiled main.js and included before the famo.us stuff gets loaded.

Comment: Have you tried adding it as a package?

Comment: Does Meteor not have a way to add single JS files not available as an Atmosphere package? If so, just download famous.js from the CDN and save it local to your project. That way Meteor's build system can package it up.

Comment: not quite that simple with the way famo.us works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried loading main.js directly in the script tag instead of using the script tag to "require" it in. I'm doing something similar where I inject the main.js code directly into the  html, but here is an example where I've split it out and it works (although I'm not using meteor.)

Clearly I'm also making a bit of an alteration to the code and not using define, but this change is straight forward. Here are the html and js...
html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Debug Output</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' />
<meta name='mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes' />
<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes' />
<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style' content='black' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.famo.us/lib/functionPrototypeBind.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.famo.us/lib/classList.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.famo.us/lib/requestAnimationFrame.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.famo.us/lib/require.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://code.famo.us/famous/0.2/famous.css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.famo.us/famous/0.2/famous.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles/app.css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='tstPackage.js'>
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
require(['famous/core/Engine','famous/core/Surface'],function(Engine,Surface) {
// Famo.us Context Example 
//var Engine  = require('famous/core/Engine');
//var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

var surface = new Surface({
    size: [200, 200],
    content: 'Hello World',
    classes: ['red-bg'],
    properties: {
    lineHeight: '200px',
    textAlign: 'center'
}
});

mainContext.add(surface);
// from https://famo.us/examples/0.2.0/core/context/example

});
```

Comment: meteor works a bit different.  It finds all js in your project and munges it all together,  it seems to do this before the CDN scripts are loaded.

Comment: actually, with a bit of hacking around, I got this to work, thanks!

Comment: As of Feb 2015, the recommended way to use Famo.us with Meteor is to add one of the [Famo.us packages](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=famous).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to import mjn:famous package into your meteor project?

meteor add mjn:famous

Comment: As of Feb 2015, the recommended way to use Famo.us with Meteor is to add one of the [Famo.us packages](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=famous).

Answer (score 0):

great question; famo.us is moving away from Yeoman / Grunt

to clean up rich's answer, here's a simple **index.html**

```
<html>
  <script src='http://code.famo.us/lib/require.js'></script>
  <script src='http://code.famo.us/famous/0.2/famous.min.js'></script>

  <script>
    require([
      'famous/core/Engine',
      'famous/core/Surface',
      'famous/core/Modifier'
    ], function(Engine, Surface, Modifier){
      var context = Engine.createContext();

      var helloSurf = new Surface({
        content: 'hello world',
        properties: {
          backgroundColor:'red'
        }
      });

      var helloMod = new Modifier({
        size: [100, 100],
        origin: [.5, 0]
      });

      context.add(helloMod).add(helloSurf);
    });
  </script>
<html>
```

Comment: As of Feb 2015, the recommended way to use Famo.us with Meteor is to add one of the [Famo.us packages](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=famous).

Comment: No. Recommended by [a few hundred people](https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-famous-views).